# PHP - Use PHPMailer in Custom Class

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMail in a class but I get an error at the line indicated below.

Can anybody see why?

```
    class SendMail {

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->debug();
        $this->includes();
    }

    public function send_mail()
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // ERROR
    }

    private function includes()
    {
        require __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
        require '/var/composer/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    private function debug()
    {
        ini_set('display_errors', 0); // 0 = Only Warnings, 1 = All Notifications
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
    }
```

I've tried moving the "new" declaration into the constructor but that didn't make any difference.

I get a 500 error and the VSCode debugger shows:

[image]

Comment: What the error say?

Comment: Are there extra points for guessing the error? Don't you think it would make sense to tell us what it is? The whole point of error messages is that they are a big clue to what the problem is...

Comment: However you can't normally put `Use` inside a class AFAIK so I'm going to guess it's (at least indirectly) related to that

Comment: It throws a 500 error.

Comment: I edited the answer to show the error message info.

Comment: ok thanks. Try moving the `Use` statements to the top of the file as I hunted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the [Traits](https://www.php.net/traits) .

I believe that `PHPMailer` is not a traits.

you need to use it as a namespace not as a trait.

```
<?php
namespace \XYZ;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class SendMail {
    // ....
}
```

note that you are need to use autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

Final Working Code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

class SendMail
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->debug();
        $this->includes();
    }

    public function send_mail()
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        echo 'Hello World';
    }

    private function includes()
    {
        require __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
        require '/var/composer/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    private function debug()
    {
        ini_set('display_errors', 0); // 0 = Only Warnings, 1 = All Notifications
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip to load the autoloader this way (if this is the only module it will probably be faster):

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$yourmail = new SendMail;
$yourmail->send("info@destination.com", "Destination Name", "Mail Subject", "<p>HTML Content</p>");

class SendMail {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->includes();
    }

    public function send($email, $name, $subject, $html_content) {
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;  
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port       = SMTP_PORT;     # to be defined
        $mail->Host       = SMTP_SERVER;   # to be defined
        $mail->Username   = SMTP_USER;     # to be defined
        $mail->Password   = SMTP_PASSWORD; # to be defined

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
        $mail->SetFrom(SMTP_USER, SMTP_NAME);
        $mail->AddReplyTo(SMTP_USER, SMTP_NAME);
        #$mail->AddCC("cc-recipient-email", "cc-recipient-name");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->MsgHTML($html_content);

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            # you are having some trouble
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private function includes()
    {
        require_once 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
        require_once 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require_once 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    }

}
```