# How to put PHPMailer function into class

Tags: php, oop, email, phpmailer

I have code as below :

```
class sendPHPMailer{

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    function __construct(){
        require "phpmailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require "phpmailer/SMTP.php";
        require "phpmailer/Exception.php";
    }

    function send_email($name = "", $email = "", $remaining_days = ""){

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

and i call that function with this code :

```
$email_send = new sendPHPMailer();
$email_send->send_email($name, $email, $days);
```

but i received error : Fatal error: Trait "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not found

Thanks

Comment: I think the `use` statements are supposed to go _outside_ the class declaration. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69394108/5947043 . And also you'd need the `require` statements before you try to `use` the items which are required. At the moment you've got it the wrong way round. And also you don't want to be re-importing the files every time you instantiate your class, that's not efficient, makes no sense, and will probably result in errors due to duplicate class definitions or similar. Just require_once at the top of your script.

Comment: Namespaces and uses needs to be on top of the script.

Comment: If you are (as your username suggests) a beginner, the single best thing you can do is learn to use composer.